# How to you join two models with a specific requirement

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models

Model A

```
class Affiliate(models.Model):
    instructor = models.OneToOneField(Profile)
```

Model B

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    instructor = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
```

My goal is in my django admin to show a list of Profiles where instructor = True, right now I am getting all of the instructors, how can I limit this list.

```
class AffiliateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['instructor']
```

This works but it gets the whole list of profiles. I only want the profiles that have instructor = True.

Say I have the following:

```
Model A - 1
Model B - 1
Model B - 2
Model B - 3

Model B - 1 and Model B - 3 Have instructor = True
Model B - 2 has instructor = False
```

When I edit Model A - 1 from the Django admin area I get a list of Profiles to link to. This list contains all three B models.

I would like the list to only include Models B - 1 and B - 3 where instructor = True.

```
Current Admin list:
Model B - 1 ( instructor = True )
Model B - 2 ( instructor = False )
Model B - 3 ( instructor = True )

Desired Admin list:
Model B - 1 ( instructor = True )
Model B - 3 ( instructor = True )
```

I have tried limiting the profile on the affiliate model with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for something like filters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Comment: Not exactly I am trying to restrict the types of Profiles I can attach to the Affiliates. I want to do this by not showing the Profiles which do not have instructor = True

Comment: I'm not sure how to phrase it but the logic would be. if profile.instructor = true show in affiliates choice list. right now I am forced to include the whole list

Comment: Or like this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

Comment: @KlausD. Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can override `get_queryset` method of class `ModelAdmin`

```
class AffiliateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['instructor']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(AffiliateAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(instructor__instructor=True)
```